# div is null in ie but in mozila and opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

```
<div id="a"></div>

if($("#a").is(':empty') )
      alert("empty");
```

In IE8, it shows `alert` but Mozila 3.6 and Opera 11 do not show the `alert`. Why?

**Answer:**

```
if(!$.trim( $("#a").html() ) )
   alert("empty");
```

this code run in ie and mozila

Comment: In Chrome it DOES show the alert

Comment: And to prove the above 3 comments: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CFWyq/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is valid and should work in those browsers. I tested it in FireFox and Chrome and it works.

Verify that you do not have any other elements in your page that also have an id of `a`. Most browsers compliant with web standards *correctly* refuse to acknowledge any duplicated elements and often it causes JavaScripts to fail due to errors.

Comment: If this is a problem of non-unique ids, don't blame the browser.  The HTML spec *requires* the values of the ids to be unique within the document.

Comment: If I'm blaming the browser, I'm blaming IE for going against that spec. I used the word 'refuse' to signify that they weren't simply poorly programmed, but that it was a conscious decision that followed spec.

Comment: I see you added the word "correctly".  That subtly changes what you were saying.  I kind of agree with you now (what FF, Chrome do is better than what IE do), though the immediate problem is still the same: the web developer has created invalid HTML.

Comment: But we should also point the finger at the folks who developed the first web browsers that implemented "permissive" parsing of HTML, and opened the door for today's rampant sloppiness in web page implementation.